# Nice Identity, Logarithm, Euler Constant

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I would like to prove the following identity:
For $x\to 1$ :

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{x^{k}}{k}\right) = - \ln(1-x) - \gamma +o(1)$$

where $o(1)=\varepsilon (x)$ with $\lim_{x \to 1} \varepsilon (x)= 0$ and $\gamma=\lim_{n \to +\infty} (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} - \ln(n))$.

I tried to use that for $t \to 0$:

$$\ln(1+t)=t- \frac{t^{2}}{2} +o(t^{2})$$

For $x \in (0,1)$ fixed, let $u_{n}(x)=\frac{x^{n}}{n}$ . We easily have that $u_{n}(x) \to_{n \to +\infty} 0$. Hence

$$\ln(1+u_{n}(x))= u_{n}(x)- \frac{u_{n}(x)^{2}}{2} + o(u_{n}^{2}(x))$$ and then I am trying to prove that : $\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{u_{n}(x)^{2}}{2}  = \gamma $  If I can do that maybe the estimation $x-\frac{x^{2}}{2} \leq \ln(1+x) \leq x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3} $ can help to prove the identity.

Comment: One difficulty with your plan: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{u_n^2(x)}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Li}_2(x^2)$.  In the limit as $x \rightarrow 1$, this is $\pi^2/12 \neq \gamma$.  (Li is a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).)

Comment: @EricTowers  Oh thanks for pointing that out, so from where the $\gamma$ will come from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-\ln(1-x)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(1+\frac{x^k}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[\frac{x^k}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{x^k}{k}\right)\right].$$ We can take $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}$ termwise, since $t\mapsto t-\ln(1+t)$ is increasing (for $t>0$). And $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac1k-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\ln(n+1)$$ tends to $\gamma$ as $n\to\infty$, because $\ln(n+1)-\ln n$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Thanks @metamorphy, you made it look easy. In fact we can prove the uniform convergence ....